Is my ceiling going to collapse?
I'm turning a metal shed into a tiny home and getting ready to hang drywall. I'm very familiar with wood construction, but these 40" gaps between the metal joists are really throwing me for a loop. Are 1x4" strappings set horizontally at 16" OC going to hold my 1/2" ceiling drywall without sagging? Could I get away with 24"? Thanks!


To make drywalling a easier I would use the braces instead of going around them. Up the wall to brace, across the brace and then the ceiling from the brace(hiding the braces).

It would be so much easier to use the braces but my wife wants to leave them exposed and drywall them in like beams for the aesthetic

Must keep wife happy for a happy home life.  Wife is god.  Make edge of the drywall even/a bit more than the brace attachments and just notch the drywall to fit.

That's is the plan but I appreciate you. It's always nice to have a second set of eyes on something and have them come up with the same solution. Also do you happen to know if that 1x4 is strong enough to hold the ceiling?

I'm actually happy that you aren't trying to attach rock to those braces... it doesn't seem like they'd be designed for a downward pull. Anyway, 1x4 on the walls and ceiling @16OC will work well, in my opinion.

Looks to me like you're gonna have to waste a foot of each panel of drywall.  Are you planning to run furring strips across the "rafters" on the whole ceiling?

Yes that's the plan.
